# Gerenciando versões do Ruby/Rails no Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Uso Windows e tenho o Ruby/Rails instalado em minhas máquinas utilizando o [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/).

Atualmente eu tenho instalado o Ruby 1.9.3 e Rails 4.0.2.

Hoje li sobre [o novo Rails 4.1](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/4/8/Rails-4-1/) e pensei:

- Se eu instalasse o Rails 4.1 em minha máquina, conseguiria trabalhar normalmente nas aplicações criadas para o 4.0?
- Se não, como gerencio versões diferentes no Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei outra resposta porque a do @Ivan_Santos esta muito curta.

---

### Atualizando o Rails no Ruby 1.9.3

- Rode `gem update rails`.

### Instalando o Ruby 2.0 e o Rails encima dele

- Tendo já a versão 1.9.3 instalada, usei `gem install pik`, depois `pik_install c:\pik` e adicionei `c:\pik` à variável `PATH` de ambiente para instalar o pik.
- Depois usei `pik install ruby 2.0` para instalar o Ruby 2.0.0.
- Depois fui em `C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit` (ou se tu instalou o DevKit manualmente, vá a pasta de instalação [que também deve ser adicionada a variável `PATH`de ambiente]) e adicionei `- C:\Users\[nome_do_meu_usuario]\.pik\rubies\Ruby-200-p195` ao arquivo `config.yml` e rodei `ruby dk.rb install` no cmd.
- Depois rodei `pik use 200` para marcar a versão 2.0.0 como ativa. (Tu pode conferir usando `ruby -v`).
- Feito isso rodei `gem install rails` para instalar o Rails 4.1.

Consegui normalmente trabalhar com aplicações feitas para versões anteriores do Rails, como as versões 3.x e 4.0, mas para isso tive que rodar `bundle install` na pasta da aplicação antes.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar algo similar ao RVM pra gerenciar versões do ruby no windows: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik

Answer (score 1):

[Link](http://blog.guilhermegarnier.com/2011/05/gerenciando-multiplas-versoes-de-ruby-no-windows/)

Nesse site link acima do @GuilhermeGarnier ensina passo a passo como fazer isso.

Dica: Você já ouviu falar em Vagrant? Tem um link do site do Nando Vieira que falar sobre ele e seria muito bom pra você não ter esse dor de cabeça futuramente
[Vagrant](http://simplesideias.com.br/usando-o-vagrant-como-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-no-windows)

Comment: [Nesta outra pergunta aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14900/tempo-de-boot-dos-testes-em-ruby-on-rails) já me foi sugerido usar o Vagrant, porém pelos tutoriais achei complicado. Estou atualmente tentando montar uma VM com Ubuntu Server manualmente. Já consegui por acessá-la por SSH (utilizando rede em modo bridge). Agora falta instalar o Git/Ruby/Rails e configurar pasta compartilhada.

Comment: Aliás, agradeço a tua atenção pra uma pergunta que já tem resposta correta. =)

Comment: Para codar Ruby em Windows sempre vai dá uma dor de cabeça. 
Tem gem que não funciona e tem outras que são muito lenta em relação ao sistema operacionais baseado em unix/linux.
O que você pode fazer e um dualboot no seu hd ou tentar usar o vangrant mesmo.

Comment: Por acaso acabei de instalar o Ruby/Rails na minha VM do VirtualBox aqui e estou impressionado com o desempenho dos geradores! Só vendo pra perceber o quanto o Ruby no Windows é lento! A única coisa que está mais lenta é via browser, que antes era por `localhost:3000` e agora por IP (`172.*.*.*:3000`). Deve ser a forma como configurei a rede (modo Bridge). Fiz usando Ubuntu Server 14.04 sem usar o Vagrant e acho que vai me servir muito bem. Abraços! =)