# Tempo de boot dos testes em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testes-de-unidade, minitest

No Ruby on Rails, utilizando a biblioteca Minitest, o tempo de execução dos testes é rápido. Porém o tempo de boot antes de cada `rake test (...)` é bem irritante. Existe algum jeito de torná-lo mais rápido?

### Atualização

Tentei instalar o Spring aqui (`gem 'spring', group: :development`) como sugeriu o @AlexTakitani.

Mas ao rodar `bundle exec spring binstub -all`, como sugere [a página deles](https://github.com/rails/spring) eu obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Sites\**<meu_app>**>bundle exec spring binstub --all
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.2 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2
.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/g
ems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/env.rb:19:in `initialize': No such file or directory
 - /dev/null (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/env.rb:19:in `open'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/env.rb:19:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:14:in `new'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:14:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/binstub.rb:136:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `new'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/binstub.rb:132:in `call'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/lib/ruby
/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/bin/spri
ng:23:in `load'
        from C:/Users/*****<meu_usuário>*****/.pik/rubies/Ruby-200-p195/bin/spri
ng:23:in `<main>'
```

### Atualização 2

No Ruby 2.0.0, atualizando o RubyGems (`gem update --system`) apenas remove o alerta, mas ainda dá o mesmo erro.

Tentei usar Ruby 1.9.3 e obtenho exatamente o mesmo erro. Rodar `gem update --system` também não adiantou aqui.

Comment: Tente atualizar o rubygems como pede a mensagem de erro: gem update --system

Comment: Mas já fique pronto pra se frustar, muito da lentidão que vc está enfrentando vem de estar usando ruby no windows, infelizmente não funciona bem.

Comment: @AlexTakitani Isso remove o alerta, mas ainda dá o mesmo erro. Idem no Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Pode ser que esteja usando a versão antiga do rubygems, tente instalar a versão mais recente

Comment: Infelizmente, nem Zeus nem Spring funcionam no windows, ambas usam fork que só funciona em *nix. Recomendo desenvolver em linux, esse foi só um dos milhares de problemas que vc encontrará desenvolvendo em windows, experiência própria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zeus e Spring que ajudariam com o tempo de boot do rails, dependem de fork que só funciona em sistemas *nix.

Recomendo que vc migre seu ambiente de desenvolvimento para linux.

Eu comecei desenvolvendo em Rails no windows, e os problemas com gems incompatíveis me fez primeiramente, desenvolver em VM, se for a melhor opção para vc, o Vagrant http://www.vagrantup.com/ ajuda bastante.

Se vc não tiver nenhum motivo para ficar em windows, migrar para o linux vai te dar muitas vantagens além da velocidade e compatibilidade do ruby.

Infelizmente não parece haver grande interesse da comunidade na compatibilidade / performance no windows.

Comment: @AlexTakitani Atualizei minha pergunta.

Comment: @AlexTakitani Ruim pro pessoal do Windows, que fica na mão. =( Acho que o jeito é continuar assim mesmo, pois rodar tudo no VirtualBox deixaria tudo muito mais lento ainda. (Na minha máquina o Windows roda bem rápido no VirtualBox, mas o Ubuntu e Mint são extremamente lentos, aponto de demorar váaaaaarios segundos para fazer coisas simples como abrir um menu do botão direito, por exemplo. =( ). Quanto à incompatibilidades de gems, até agora só tive problemas com a própria Spring e Zeus, no mais tudo funcionou. Agradeço a tua paciência. =)

Comment: Andrey, não rode ambiente gráfico na vm, rode em modo texto, acesse via ssh, compartilhe uma pasta, e rode o resto no windows mesmo.http://simplesideias.com.br/usando-o-vagrant-como-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-no-windows